# Connecting Google Tag back to Google Analytics

Tags: google-tag-manager, google-analytics-4

I have created a Google Tag which i have implemented in Google Tag Manager and configured the tag with google analytics. I have a measurement ID that can be found in a Google container. However, i do not know where the google analytics platform is nor can i link the measurement ID to a new google analytics.

The tag is working and it has being tested. How to link it with google analytics?

I have created new account, property but they all giving me new Measurement ID which is different from what i have implemented on the website.

[image]